# Python == Function to Count All Integers Below Defined Variable, Inclusive

Tags: python, variables, arguments

Sorry I have to ask such a simple question, but I've been trying to do this for a while with no luck, despite searching around.
I'm trying to define a function that will get user input for X, and then add every integer from 0 to X, and display the output.

For example, if the user inputs 5, the result should be the sum of 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5.

I can't figure out how to prompt the user for the variable, and then pass this variable into the argument of the function. Thanks for your help.

```
def InclusiveRange(end):
        end = int(input("Enter Variable: ")
        while start <= end:
                start += 1
        print("The total of the numbers, from 0 to %d,  is:  %d" % (end, start))
```

Comment: Just a note about coding style: the convention in Python is to use CamelCase for class names and lower_case_with_underscores for function names. So your function would preferably be called "inclusive_range", or even better a name which actually describes what the function does (e.g. "sum_zero_to_n").

Comment: you are aware that this value has a closed form solution? `InclusiveRange = lambda end: (end * (end+1))/2`

Answer (score 1):

Just delete argument "end" from function header and use your function.

```
InclusiveRange()
```

or define code in other way:

```
def InclusiveRange(end):        
    while start <= end:
            start += 1
    print("The total of the numbers, from 0 to %d,  is:  %d" % (end, start))
end = int(input("Enter Variable: ")
InclusiveRange(end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `itertools` version:

```
>>> from itertools import count, islice
>>> def sum_to_n(n):
...     return sum(islice(count(), 0, n + 1))
>>>
>>> sum_to_n(int(input('input integer: ')))
input integer: 5
15
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should take the user input out of the function, and instead call the function once you have received the user input.
- You also need to store the sum in a separate variable to start, otherwise you're only adding 1 each iteration. (I renamed it to `index` in this example as it reflects it's purpose more).

---

```
def InclusiveRange(end):
    index = 0
    sum = 0
    while index <= end:
        sum += start
        index += 1
    print("The total of the numbers, from 0 to %d,  is:  %d" % (end, sum))

end = int(input("Enter Variable: "))
InclusiveRange(end)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/CLfl)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop, use a `range` object, which you can easily send to `sum()`. Also, you're never actually using the passed `end` variable, immediately throwing it away and binding `end` to a new value. Pass it in from outside the function.

```
def inclusive_range(end):
        num = sum(range(end+1))
        print("The total of the numbers, from 0 to {}, is: {}".format(end, num))

inclusive_range(int(input("Enter Variable: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [math formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) to calculate the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to N.

```
def InclusiveRange(end):
    ''' Returns the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to end. '''
    assert end >= 1
    return end * (end + 1) / 2

end = int(input("Enter N: "))
print(InclusiveRange(end))
```